# Pandas Join into Comma Separated String, But One Record For Each Value in a Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do some data manipulation on a Pandas DataFrame and I want to group by / categorize by a single column, but do so for each different corresponding group of rows.

For example, I have the below DataFrame -

| sport | league | home | away | book | bet | odds | market |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Aaron Nesmith | 1100 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Bam Adebayo | 350 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Bennedict Mathurin | 850 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Buddy Hield | 900 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Caleb Martin | 1100 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Gabe Vincent | 950 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Jimmy Butler | 550 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Myles Turner | 600 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Tyler Herro | 600 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Tyrese Haliburton | 800 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Aaron Nesmith | 1600 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Andrew Nembhard | 2000 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Bam Adebayo | 360 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Buddy Hield | 850 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Caleb Martin | 1600 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Gabe Vincent | 1000 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Jimmy Butler | 470 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Myles Turner | 500 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Tyler Herro | 550 | First Basket |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Tyrese Haliburton | 950 | First Basket |

Here is the data as a copy / paste dict -

```
{'sport': {180: 'basketball', 182: 'basketball', 184: 'basketball', 186: 'basketball', 188: 'basketball', 190: 'basketball', 192: 'basketball', 194: 'basketball', 196: 'basketball', 198: 'basketball', 210: 'basketball', 211: 'basketball', 212: 'basketball', 213: 'basketball', 214: 'basketball', 215: 'basketball', 216: 'basketball', 217: 'basketball', 218: 'basketball', 219: 'basketball'}, 'league': {180: 'NBA', 182: 'NBA', 184: 'NBA', 186: 'NBA', 188: 'NBA', 190: 'NBA', 192: 'NBA', 194: 'NBA', 196: 'NBA', 198: 'NBA', 210: 'NBA', 211: 'NBA', 212: 'NBA', 213: 'NBA', 214: 'NBA', 215: 'NBA', 216: 'NBA', 217: 'NBA', 218: 'NBA', 219: 'NBA'}, 'home': {180: 'Miami Heat', 182: 'Miami Heat', 184: 'Miami Heat', 186: 'Miami Heat', 188: 'Miami Heat', 190: 'Miami Heat', 192: 'Miami Heat', 194: 'Miami Heat', 196: 'Miami Heat', 198: 'Miami Heat', 210: 'Miami Heat', 211: 'Miami Heat', 212: 'Miami Heat', 213: 'Miami Heat', 214: 'Miami Heat', 215: 'Miami Heat', 216: 'Miami Heat', 217: 'Miami Heat', 218: 'Miami Heat', 219: 'Miami Heat'}, 'away': {180: 'Indiana Pacers', 182: 'Indiana Pacers', 184: 'Indiana Pacers', 186: 'Indiana Pacers', 188: 'Indiana Pacers', 190: 'Indiana Pacers', 192: 'Indiana Pacers', 194: 'Indiana Pacers', 196: 'Indiana Pacers', 198: 'Indiana Pacers', 210: 'Indiana Pacers', 211: 'Indiana Pacers', 212: 'Indiana Pacers', 213: 'Indiana Pacers', 214: 'Indiana Pacers', 215: 'Indiana Pacers', 216: 'Indiana Pacers', 217: 'Indiana Pacers', 218: 'Indiana Pacers', 219: 'Indiana Pacers'}, 'book': {180: 'DraftKings', 182: 'DraftKings', 184: 'DraftKings', 186: 'DraftKings', 188: 'DraftKings', 190: 'DraftKings', 192: 'DraftKings', 194: 'DraftKings', 196: 'DraftKings', 198: 'DraftKings', 210: 'FanDuel', 211: 'FanDuel', 212: 'FanDuel', 213: 'FanDuel', 214: 'FanDuel', 215: 'FanDuel', 216: 'FanDuel', 217: 'FanDuel', 218: 'FanDuel', 219: 'FanDuel'}, 'bet': {180: 'Aaron Nesmith', 182: 'Bam Adebayo', 184: 'Bennedict Mathurin', 186: 'Buddy Hield', 188: 'Caleb Martin', 190: 'Gabe Vincent', 192: 'Jimmy Butler', 194: 'Myles Turner', 196: 'Tyler Herro', 198: 'Tyrese Haliburton', 210: 'Aaron Nesmith', 211: 'Andrew Nembhard', 212: 'Bam Adebayo', 213: 'Buddy Hield', 214: 'Caleb Martin', 215: 'Gabe Vincent', 216: 'Jimmy Butler', 217: 'Myles Turner', 218: 'Tyler Herro', 219: 'Tyrese Haliburton'}, 'odds': {180: '1100', 182: '350', 184: '850', 186: '900', 188: '1100', 190: '950', 192: '550', 194: '600', 196: '600', 198: '800', 210: '1600', 211: '2000', 212: '360', 213: '850', 214: '1600', 215: '1000', 216: '470', 217: '500', 218: '550', 219: '950'}, 'market': {180: 'First Basket', 182: 'First Basket', 184: 'First Basket', 186: 'First Basket', 188: 'First Basket', 190: 'First Basket', 192: 'First Basket', 194: 'First Basket', 196: 'First Basket', 198: 'First Basket', 210: 'First Basket', 211: 'First Basket', 212: 'First Basket', 213: 'First Basket', 214: 'First Basket', 215: 'First Basket', 216: 'First Basket', 217: 'First Basket', 218: 'First Basket', 219: 'First Basket'}}
```

What I'd like to achieve is the sample output below. The goal of this output is for each 'book' in the DataFrame to group by the bet such that the odds for that book are first and the remaining odds are joined behind it with a '/' separator.

| sport | league | home | away | book | bet | market | odds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Aaron Nesmith | First Basket | 1100/1600 |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Aaron Nesmith | First Basket | 1600/1100 |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | DraftKings | Bam Adebayo | First Basket | 350/360 |
| basketball | NBA | Miami Heat | Indiana Pacers | FanDuel | Bam Adebayo | First Basket | 360/350 |

I've tried this code and while it gets me close I can't get it to also have one record per book.

```py
print(single_game.groupby(["book", "bet"]).agg({"odds": "/".join}).reset_index())
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there are not more than two books per bet?

Comment: @harryhaller there are approximately 10 per bet, but didn't want to overload the question with all that data.

Answer (score 0):

Filter `book` first in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and assign `odd` by mapping `bet` by another `DataFrame`, last join togheter. If only one value missing in another DataFrame ouput is `NaN`:

```
df1 = df[df['book'].eq('DraftKings')]
df2 = df[df['book'].eq('FanDuel')]

df11 = df1.assign(odds = df1['odds'] + '/' + df1['bet'].map(df2.set_index('bet')['odds']))
df22 = df2.assign(odds = df2['odds'] + '/' + df2['bet'].map(df1.set_index('bet')['odds']))

df = pd.concat([df11, df22]).sort_values('bet')
```

---

```
print (df)
          sport league        home            away        book  \
180  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers  DraftKings   
210  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers     FanDuel   
211  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers     FanDuel   
182  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers  DraftKings   
212  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers     FanDuel   
184  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers  DraftKings   
186  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers  DraftKings   
213  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers     FanDuel   
188  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers  DraftKings   
214  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers     FanDuel   
190  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers  DraftKings   
215  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers     FanDuel   
192  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers  DraftKings   
216  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers     FanDuel   
217  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers     FanDuel   
194  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers  DraftKings   
218  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers     FanDuel   
196  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers  DraftKings   
198  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers  DraftKings   
219  basketball    NBA  Miami Heat  Indiana Pacers     FanDuel   

                    bet       odds        market  
180       Aaron Nesmith  1100/1600  First Basket  
210       Aaron Nesmith  1600/1100  First Basket  
211     Andrew Nembhard        NaN  First Basket  
182         Bam Adebayo    350/360  First Basket  
212         Bam Adebayo    360/350  First Basket  
184  Bennedict Mathurin        NaN  First Basket  
186         Buddy Hield    900/850  First Basket  
213         Buddy Hield    850/900  First Basket  
188        Caleb Martin  1100/1600  First Basket  
214        Caleb Martin  1600/1100  First Basket  
190        Gabe Vincent   950/1000  First Basket  
215        Gabe Vincent   1000/950  First Basket  
192        Jimmy Butler    550/470  First Basket  
216        Jimmy Butler    470/550  First Basket  
217        Myles Turner    500/600  First Basket  
194        Myles Turner    600/500  First Basket  
218         Tyler Herro    550/600  First Basket  
196         Tyler Herro    600/550  First Basket  
198   Tyrese Haliburton    800/950  First Basket  
219   Tyrese Haliburton    950/800  First Basket
```